# MySQLi count(*) always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a table and thought that this was the correct way to do that:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`;");
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

But counts always returns `(int)1`. If I use the same query in phpMyAdmin I get the right result. It sits in a table so I tried testing `$count[0]` as well, but that returns `NULL`.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have to fetch that one record, it will contain the result of Count()

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo '#: ', $row[0];
```

Comment: Thanks!
So num_rows only should be used for `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT COUNT`?

Comment: More or les, yes. `num_rows` can tell you how many result records _have been transferred_ to the client. If that's the number you want to know num_rows is what you should use. If you want to know how many records there are in the database (without transferring the data to the client) use Count(*).

Answer (score 12):

Always try to do an associative fetch, that way you can easy get what you want in multiple case result

Here's an example

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cityCount FROM myCity")
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['cityCount']." rows in table myCity.";
```

Comment: Curious what do you mean by multiple case result? A select with multiple counts using case statements?

Answer (score 3):

I find this way more readable:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('select count(*) as `c` from `table`');
$count = $result->fetch_object()->c;
echo "there are {$count} rows in the table";
```

Not that I have anything against arrays...

Answer (score 0):

$result->num_rows; only returns the number of row(s) affected by a query. When you are performing a count(*) on a table it only returns one row so you can not have an other result than 1.

Comment: Incorrect. mysqli_result::$num_rows returns the row count of a result set. mysqli::$affected_rows returns the number of rows affected by a query.