# SQL count all doesn't execute in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
if($sql = $db->query("Count (*) FROM post_items")){
        echo mysqli_num_rows($sql);
}
```

what's wrong with my code? is this the correct way to echo the total of row in a table?

Comment: Missing `SELECT` in your query try this `SELECT Count(*) FROM post_items`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid didn't work too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQLi count(\*) always returns 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613074/mysqli-count-always-returns-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be

```
select count(*) FROM post_items
```

but echoing

```
mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

will always give `1` as the ans, because count function returns only one row.

Rather fetch the details and show the count

```
$row = $sql->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: then that's not what I want. I need to know the total row in the table. like 50 customers has bought an item.

Comment: echoing the count will do that for you, `mysqli_num_rows` returns no of rows not the data of rows

Comment: to get data you will have to fetch the result and then display it, check updated ans

Answer (score 2):

No it is not; you will always get a return value of 1.

Why? Because you are in essence *double-counting*. The query executes a `COUNT` aggregate on the table returning a single row with the counted number. `mysqli_num_rows` is then counting the number of rows in this result set - the single row - and returns 1.

Try, the following line instead, which should fetch the first (only) column returned of the first (only) row in the result set.

```
echo $sql->fetch_row()[0]
```

---

*Note you're also missing a `SELECT` keyword in your SQL statement.*

Answer (score -3):

It should be

```
if($sql = $db->query("select count(*) FROM post_items")){
        echo mysqli_num_rows($sql);
}
```