# PHP: else condition is not working in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have designed a admin login page. The if condition is working but else condition is not. After putting wrong username or password it shows blank on the same page.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $pass= $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($DBCONNECT, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE userid='$userid' and pass='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());

    //$count=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if($count == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;//$_POST['userid'];
        echo "hiii";
        //header("Location:add_menu.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the $count value when wrong password ?

Comment: Use `mysqli_error` instead of `mysql_error()` in your code.

Comment: If non of the echos is executed, this may indicate that `$_POST['submit']` is not set. Have you checked that?

Comment: @luator Nishant insisted the inner if and else part. not the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: @Gunaseelan: I know, but since both cases of the if-else have an `echo` and there is still no output, this means, that the inner `if` is not reached at all. There are only two possible reasons: The program crashes with an silent error before the `if` (probably the `or die` part) or it does not even enter the outer `if` (it is nowhere verified that it does enter it).

Comment: Just a note you may like. Try using PDO instead if mysql. It is more secure so you are less likely going have a security breach.

Answer (score 1):

You used `mysql_error();` which is causing the error of blank page.

Use the below code will fix your problem.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($DBCONNECT,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Remove `or die(mysqli_error($link))` from your code that will work fine for you.

**Note:** [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) can be used for Procedural style only not for object oriented style.

Comment: Thank u all. But removing  die(mysql_error($link)) worked. Thank u very much Gunaseelan.

Comment: @Nishant Check out my updated answer. If you use the same code for different table which has more than 1 row, the result will come as 1 only. So use the code that I have given. For reference check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613074/mysqli-count-always-returns-1)

Comment: @Nishant If my answer helped you to overcome your problem, Kindly accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: @Gunaseelan I think you'll find that `mysqli_num_rows` does exist: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @Martin Thanks Martin

Comment: I think your new code will fail if you enter a wrong password or username. Instead of counting the number of hits, like the OP did, you try to access the first row of the result. This will fail if the result is empty.

Comment: @Gunaseelan: Where should this '0 or 1' output come from? The query was a simple `SELECT * FROM ...` so the output should be either a list of rows (with values depending on the table) or an empty result. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code? Difference is putting `if($count)` instead of `if($count==1)`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $pass= $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($DBCONNECT, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE userid='$userid' and pass='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());

    //$count=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if($count)
    {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;//$_POST['userid'];
        echo "hiii";
        //header("Location:add_menu.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use count==1 than a true count, but also to check if there is more than one row in the db, as you suggested.

Comment: And why not `$count > 0` !!1

Comment: @Saty: I guess multiple hits would also be strange and may indicate some error (there shouldn't be multiple users with the same name).

Comment: @EngrArefin: Since both cases of the if-else have an output, but the OP says that there is no output at all, the problem has to lie somewhere else (no matter what `$count` looks like, one of the two cases has to be executed when the `if` is reached).

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli Also make result as object so you can do this :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$userid' and pass='$pass'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

your mysqli_error only will show if statement wrong and i don't think you will put wrong statement but good in development.

then you can check if statement works by if and put this :

```
echo $sql->num_rows;
```

can put in variable :

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql) to $count = $sql->num_rows
```

or

```
if($sql->num_rows == 0) {
 // here your blank result for error
} else {
 // show result here.
}
```

Link : [Check PHP Site Mysqli Num Rows Result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)