# PHP MySQL not returning the correct count

Tags: php, mysqli

I have verified my query using phpMyAdmin. The count is 130. But my code is giving me a count of 1.

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM webvulns";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
confirm_query($result2);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
echo $rowcount;
// Free result set.
mysqli_free_result($result2);
```

Comment: Take a look here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613074/mysqli-count-always-returns-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_num_rows` returns a count of rows. You only have 1 row. That row will have `130` in it. Fetch the result.

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as da_count FROM webvulns";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
confirm_query($result2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$rowcount=$row['da_count'];
echo $rowcount;
// Free result set.
mysqli_free_result($result2);
```

Comment: Don't know how to do that. I was using this as an example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Updated with example. When in doubt refer to the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it will work properly

```
  $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM webvulns";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    echo $row[0];
```